# How to read binary file as string in c++

Tags: c++, binaryfiles

In binary file, there are some information which is student id, name and GPA for three students. I want to read them. id is integer type and GPA is float type. name is string type and the size is not fixed because the size of name is different each other. I want to get id, name and GPA for each student at function of student class.

probably, I think I have a problem at loading name. 
I want to know how to fix it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Student {
private:
    int id;
    string name;
    float GPA;
    string line;

public:
    Student() {};
    Student(string line_) :line(line_) {  };
    int get_id();
    string get_name();
    float get_GPA();
    void save_bi(ofstream &of);
    void load_bi(ifstream &inf);
    void save_txt(ofstream &of);
    void print();

};


void Student::load_bi(ifstream &inf)
{
    inf.read((char*)&id, sizeof(id));
    inf.read((char*)&name, sizeof(name));
    inf.read((char*)&GPA, sizeof(GPA));
    //a.push_back(name);
}


int main()
{
    ifstream inf;
    inf.open("student_data.bin", ios::in | ios::binary);
    if (!inf.is_open())
        cout << "file open failure." << endl;

    Student A;
    A.load_bi(inf);
    A.print();

    Student B;
    B.load_bi(inf);
    B.print();

    Student C;
    C.load_bi(inf);
    C.print();

    inf.close();


    return 0;
}
```

it is error message.

```
inline void _Container_base12::_Orphan_all() noexcept
    {   // orphan all iterators
 #if _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 2
    if (_Myproxy != nullptr)
        {   // proxy allocated, drain it
        _Lockit _Lock(_LOCK_DEBUG);

        for (_Iterator_base12 **_Pnext = &_Myproxy->_Myfirstiter;
            *_Pnext != nullptr; *_Pnext = (*_Pnext)->_Mynextiter)
            (*_Pnext)->_Myproxy = nullptr;
        _Myproxy->_Myfirstiter = nullptr;
        }
 #endif /* _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 2 */
    }
```

Exception thrown: read access violation. 
_Pnext was 0x13AED64.

Comment: Can you provide more information on the structure of this binary file? Is the string null-terminated & ASCII encoding? Is the GPA float *after* the variable-length string? You still need to open the file as binary, opening it as a text/string file will just misinterpret the integer and float data as characters.

Comment: `inf.read((char*)&name, sizeof(name));` -- If you look at the parameters, especially the second one, and read the documentation on `read`, you should see that this could never work.  The `sizeof(name)` does not give you the number of characters.  It is literally the size of the `std::string` type, which is a compile-time value and doesn't change.  If you had a million characters in `name`, `sizeof(name)` would be a never-changing, small number.  You cannot read into types like `std::string` using this "binary" method.

Comment: a `std::string` is not just a sequence of characters. It does contain pointers and what not, you cannot simply write its binary representation to file and read it back to get a `std::string`

Comment: What you want to do is serialize your object, not just blindly read / write as binary.  It seems that this binary file reading / writing errors come up very often here, and I'm sure there is a duplicate question and answer.

Comment: @Romen I'm sorry to miss information. string has no null-terminated and no ASCII encoding. My binary file consists of student ID, name and GPA in this sequence.

Comment: @beomjinseo, Let's assume the student ID is a 32-bit integer. That means your student name starts at byte 4 (counting from 0). If the name can be any length, how do you know how many bytes to read? Which byte does the GPA start? Null-terminated strings are the convention for indicating the end of a string, how does this file indicate the size of the name in between that integer and float? What encoding *is* the string in if not ASCII?

Comment: In general, strings are variable length fields.  You will need to either write the length, then read that length into a string variable; or read until a terminator character (like nul) is found.

Answer (score 1):

A simple example of serializing your structure:

```
class Student
{
    int id;
    string name;
    float GPA;
    string line;
public:
    void binary_write(std::ostream& out) const;
    void binary_read(std::istream& input);
};

void Student::binary_write(std::ostream& out) const
{
    out.write(&id, sizeof(id));
    std::string::size_type length(name.length());
    out.write(&length, sizeof(length));
    out.write(name.data(), length);
    out.write(&GPA, sizeof(GPA));
    length = line.length();
    out.write(line.data(), length);
}

void Student::binary_read(std::istream& input)
{
    input.read(&id, sizeof(id));
    std::string::size_type length;
    input.read(&length, sizeof(length));
    char * temp = new char[length];
    input.read(temp, length);
    name = std::string(temp);
    input.read(&GPA, sizeof(GPA));
    delete[] temp;
    input.read(&length, sizeof(length));
    temp = new char[length];
    input.read(temp, length);
    line = std::string(temp);
    delete [] temp;
}
```

The above code uses the technique of writing the length of the string, followed by the string contents.  The reading consists of using a temporary buffer, then reads the text into the buffer and creates a `std::string` from the buffer.

There are other methods to read in a string (search your C++ reference for "c++ string input iterator), but this illustrates the point.

The problem with writing pointers, and `std::string` contains pointers, is that there is no guarantee that the operating system will load your program into the exact same place in memory at every invocation.

The `binary_write` function is declared as `const` since it doesn't change any of the `Student` data members.  This technique is called "const correctness".  Search the internet for its definition.

The default accessibility for `class` is private, so I removed the `private` from the section declaring the variables.